# Empirix hammer and mobile testing is it possible?

Tags: mobile, ui-automation

I am looking into the feasibility of automating tests for some mobile apps that have calling functionality.

I have been looking around for automated ui testing for mobiles which seems feasible but they all stop short of simulating any voice data.

We currently have an old [hammer](http://www.empirix.com/) and are looking in to upgrading.

Is it possible to integrate the in call simulation functionality of the hammer with the UI functionality of something like [squish](http://www.froglogic.com/products/index.php) or [countdown](http://www.bsquare.com/countdown.aspx)?

Some alternative possibilities would be helpful as so far i haven't found a tool that does what i want.

dont all jump at once!

Answer (score 0):

IQ Services has an extremely configurable voice/telecommunications test environment that can be applied in many ways - we should talk about your needs.  We automate many test calling processes - perhaps we can assist.  Give us a call at 612.243.6700 & ask for me - Mike Burke